# cvDilate/cvErode: How to avoid connection between separated objects?

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, image-manipulation

I would like to separate objects in OpenCv like the following image it shows: [image]
But if I am using cvDilate or cvErode the objects grow together... how to do that with OpenCv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know OpenCV does not have "dilation with XOR" (although that would be very nice to have).
To get similar results you might try eroding (as in 'd'), and using the eroded centers as seeds for a Voronoi segmentation which you could then AND with the original image.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will need to write your own dilate function and then add xor functionality yourself.

Per the opencv documentation, here is the rule that cvdilate uses:

dst=dilate(src,element):  dst(x,y)=max((x',y') in element))src(x+x',y+y')

Here is pseudocode for a starting point (this does not include xor code):

```
void my_dilate(img) {

  for(i = 0; i < img.height; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < img.width; j++) {
       max_pixel = get_max_pixel_in_window(img, i, j);
       img.pixel(i,j) = max_pixel;
    }
  }  

}

int get_max_pixel_in_window(img, center_row, center_col) {
   int window_size = 3;
   int cur_max = 0;
   for(i = -window_size; i <= window_size; i++) {
     for(j = -window_size; j <= window_size; j++) {
        int cur_col = center_col + i; 
        int cur_row = center_row + j;
        if(out_of_bounds(img, cur_col, cur_row)) {
            continue;
        }
        int cur_pix = img.pixel(center_row + i, center_col + j);
        if(cur_pix > cur_max) {
           cur_max = cur_pix;
        }
     }
   }
   return cur_max;
}

// returns true if the x, y coordinate is outside of the image
int out_of_bounds(img, x, y) {
  if(x >= img.width || x < 0 || y >= img.height || y <= 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you  please tell me the use of this function " out_of_bounds(img, cur_col, cur_row) ".
It  will be good if you write its pseudo code .

Answer (score 0):

after erosion and dilate try thresholding the image to eliminate weak elements. Only strong regions should remain and thus improve the object separation. By the way could you be a little more clear about your problem with cvDilate or cvErode.